# Call crystal reports through java

Tags: java, swing, jsp, crystal-reports, swt

I have one crystal report and i want to create one front end application using java to show the reports to user. Can any one give me the code how can i invoke crystal reports through a java application?

Comment: You should let people know from what UI technology stack - Swing, JSP, SWT, etc.

Comment: Shalma, you added the swing, jsp, and swt tags.  They are mutually exclusive.  Swing is for standard desktop programs.  JSP is for web application delivered over the web browser.  SWT is an alternative to Swing with a more native look-and-feel.

Answer (score 3):

There is a third party tool called [crystal clear](http://www.inetsoftware.de/products/crystal-clear) that we use at my company that does this.  I'll give you a few words of caution though, it is not free and you do need to make changes to your application to support it.  We use it with jsps but it's pure java so you could, theoretically, use any of the front end technologies you've tagged this question with.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to do this using [Crystal Reports for Eclipse](http://www.sap.com/solutions/sapbusinessobjects/sme/reporting-dashboarding/reporting/eclipse/index.epx). This has APIs for both Java applications and web applications.

Comment: This is what I use, and it's been invaluable, especially when using java to pass lists of javabeans to the report in place of the standard db data, giving better control of content.